# Active perfect stem conjugation and forms of esse

Tags: verbs, language-evolution, morphology, conjugation, esse

Many forms formed from the perfect stem (*habitav-*, *fec-*, *tetig-*, and others) resemble forms of *esse*.
It looks as if a form of *esse* was directly attached to the perfect stem.
In perfect conjunctive an *-e-* seems to be added and the *s>r* is explained by rhotacism.
In pluperfect conjunctive the *-ess-* is replaced with *-iss-*.
These sound changes are easy to accept, so the analogy between the two conjugations is clearly similar.

Is this similarity between *esse* and perfect stem forms a coincidence?
How did it come about?
The corresponding forms of *esse* are used explicitly in the passive counterparts of these forms.
Were the active forms originally perhaps a combination of an active perfect participle and *esse*?

The active perfect indicative forms (*feci*, *fecisti*, …) do not have this similarity to *esse*.
I will completely ignore those forms for this question; they can be explored in separate questions.
This question concerns pluperfect and future perfect of indicative and perfect and pluperfect of conjunctive.
Probably the perfect active infinitive should be included as well.

There was a separate [question about the vowel length in *feceris* and similar forms](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6414/79).
Whether the vowel lengths match perfectly between *esse* and perfect stem forms, the similarity is striking.

Answer (score 6):

### It's probably a coincidence.

Preface: My main source for this entire answer is [*The Origin of the Italic Imperfect Subjunctive* by J. H. Jasanoff (Vandenhoek and Ruprecht, 1991)](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/%7Ejasanoff/pdf/Origin%20of%20Italic%20imperfect%20subjunctive.pdf). If this is contradicted by more recent scholarship, please feel free to correct me!

All but one of the example words given are in the second person singular, because this shows off the vowel lengths more reliably (and because it's what Jasanoff does).

#### Imperfect Subjunctive

The imperfect subjunctive in Latin was formed from a Proto-Italic morpheme reconstructed as **-sē-*. Where this morpheme comes from is unclear, since it doesn't line up with anything in PIE, but it doesn't seem to be related to *sim, sīs, sit* (Proto-Italic **si-ēm*, **si-ēs*, **si-ēd*).

In most verbs, this rhotacized: **amā-sē-s* > *amārēs*, **face-sē-s* > *facerēs*, and so on. But in the rare athematic verbs, the *s* appears as itself or assimilates: **es-sē-s* > *essēs*, **vel-sē-s* > *vellēs*.

When I was first learning, I was taught to form the imperfect subjunctive by attaching personal endings to the infinitive. But this isn't correct either: the infinitive was formed with an ending **-si*, with a short vowel. So using this rule will get the vowel lengths wrong.

#### Future Perfect Indicative

This tense comes from "the S-future of the perfect". In other words, the future morpheme *-(i)s-* attached to the perfect stem. (The "S-future" is very common for the actual future tense in Ancient Greek: present *lyō* → future *lysō*. But in Latin, it was replaced with a relative of *fiō* in the first and second conjugations, and the original subjunctive in the third and fourth.)

So a form like *amāveris* comes from *amā-v-is-(i)s*. The similarity to *eris* seems to be coincidence: vowel reduction and rhotacism turned *-is-is* into *-eris*. But I'm not sure where *eris* itself (as in "you will be") comes from, so I can't be sure they're unrelated.

#### Perfect Subjunctive

This comes from the optative of the S-future of the perfect: the optative morpheme *-ī-* added on to the future perfect stem. The long vowel distinguished this from the future perfect indicative at first, but [as Alex B points out](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6418/406), the distinction vanished by Classical times. So this *amāveris* comes from older *amāverīs*, from *amā-v-is-ī-s*. Once again, the similarity seems coincidental.

Notably, the S-future of the present used to be used for the actual future in Old Latin (*faxō* "I will do" < *fac-s-ō* is attested), while the optative of the S-future of the present was used for the present subjunctive (*faxīs* "you should do" < *fac-s-īs*).

#### Pluperfect Subjunctive

This one is formed from the subjunctive morpheme **-sē-* (as seen in the imperfect) combined with the S-future of the perfect (as seen in the future perfect). *Amāvissēs* comes from *amā-v-is-sē-s*, and the additional consonant prevents both vowel reduction and rhotacism.

So this one is actually half-cognate with *essēs*: the *-sēs* ending is the same. But once again I was taught wrong: the perfect infinitive comes from *amā-v-is-si*, with a short vowel. That *-si* is (probably) not related to the subjunctive *-sē* except by coincidence.

#### Pluperfect Indicative

TODO: I don't actually know where this one comes from.

Comment: Great answer. There was one side note that I didn't quite understand: *But in Latin, a relative of fiō and the PIE subjunctive turned into a new future tense.* Are we to understand that there is a *fi-* somewhere in *amabo* and/or *mittam*?

Comment: @Cerberus My understanding is that *mittēs* comes from the original subjunctive, while the *-bī-* in *amābīs* comes from *bhuH* "become". PIE *bh* turned into *f* at the beginning of words in Latin, but *b* in the middle, so the stem *bhuH* turned into *fiō*, *fuī*, and also that *-bī-*. I'll edit this in.

Comment: The connection between the future *-bi-* and *fi-* or *fu-* would be worth asking separately. If someone is wondering about that, they are unlikely to take a closer look at this question. (@Cerberus)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Done!

Comment: Regarding *erit*, L&S mentions old forms *escit* and *esit*:  “fut. escit for erit, XII. Tab. ap. Gell. 20, 1, 25: esit, XII. Tab. ap. Fest. s. v. nec, p. 162 Müll.: escunt for erunt", Cic. Leg. 2, 24, 60, 3, 3, 9” Not sure what to make of it, though. Rhotatic shift is obvious, but he *-c-* is... interesting.