# What's the deal with the extra U in 'mortuus'?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, participle

The verb *mori* ("to die") has the unusual past participle *mortuus* ("dead").
The stem of the participle is *mortu-*, the only example of a past participle stem ending in a vowel I can think of.
(If my memory fails, please let me know!)
I would instead expect *mortus* or perhaps *moritus*.

The future participle is *moriturus*.
This would give a little discrepancy between *mortus* (from which one might expect *morturus*) and the future participle, but this is not unique.
While usually the future participle comes directly from the past one by adding *-ur-*, there are examples of similar behaviour, like *ortus* and *oriturus*.
See [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6442/79) for discrepancies between past and future participles.

I never understood why *mortuus* has two Us instead of being simply *mortus*.
Can anyone explain how this form came about?
Was this participle always like this before the classical times?
Are there other similar past participles in Latin?

There is a [separate question about the pronunciation of *mortuus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6475/79), and all evidence points towards it being trisyllabic.
Both Us are therefore vowels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an interesting relic of the PIE conjugation system.

In Proto-Indo-European, there were quite a lot of different "participles" (or derived adjectives, it's not clear how much they were considered "the same as" the source verbs). One of these was *-tós*, which became the perfect passive participle *-tus* in Latin and the adjectivizer *-tós* in Greek (as well as, eventually, *-ed* in English).

But there was another one, which changed significantly in Latin: *-wós*, the perfect *active* participle. In Latin, this was the source of *-v-* in the perfect stems. But in a few specific verbs, the perfect active participle survived on its own as an adjective. *Mortuus* is one of those. *Vīvus* is another. (The suffix *-wós* itself survived as [*-uus*/*-vus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/3055/406), so a Roman might analyze *mortuus* as *mort-* + *-uus*.)

The verb that would become *morior* also had its own *-tós* participle, which would have been something like **mortus* by the time it reached Latin. (We know this from cognates like Sanskrit *mṛtá* "dead".) But the *-wós* adjective that would become *mortuus* was far more popular and ended up displacing it. *Vīvus*, whose corresponding verb (ironically) died out completely, just continued to be an adjective.

Comment: Interesting! It seems plausible that the active perfect participle together with *esse* lead to much of Latin perfect stem conjugation, which would answer [the question on perfect and *esse*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6422/79). Is that the way the *-w-* of *-wós* became the *-v-* in Latin perfect stems?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta and Draconis, If answer was as simple as what is written here now, Latin would probably have \**morvus*. Page for root [\**mer-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/mer-) mentions reconstructed 3 adjectives meaning "dead": \**mr̥-tós*, \**mr̥-t-wós*, \**mr̥-wós* (the last one preserved in Proto-Celtic). Michiel de Vaan (2008)'s dictionary in entry for *morior* (page 390) says: 「The formation of \**mrtu̯o-* ‘dead’ for PIE \**mr̥to-* (as in Slavic) may be due to a contamination with \**mr̥u̯o-* as attested in Celtic.」 (Proto-Slavic had \**mьrtvъ*.)

Comment: And I think that *vīvō*, *vīvere* can be considered to be the corresponding verb for adjective *vīvus*.