# What is the origin of the future suffix -b-?

Tags: language-evolution, morphology, conjugation, future-tense

I read in [this answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6422/active-perfect-stem-conjugation-and-forms-of-esse/6473) that there may be a relation between the future endings *-bo, -bis,* etc. on the one hand and the verb *fio* "become" on the other. Is this true? If so, do we have any more details on how that happened

Bonus side question: are *fio* and *facio* related, cf. utriusque participle *factus*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Main question: they come from the same PIE root.

The verb *fīō* comes from (the zero-grade of) the PIE root **bhuH-*, "to become". This led to a Proto-Italic verb **fui-*. In Proto-Italic, the phoneme **f* is thought to have been a bilabial fricative, voiceless [ɸ] at the start of a word and voiced [β] everywhere else.

Somewhere around Proto-Italic, this verb **fui-* started to be used for certain periphrastic formations: **fuā-* (subjunctive) for the imperfect, and **fui-* (indicative) for the future. Then, just as in the verb *fīō* itself, the **u* disappeared before these other vowels.

This left Proto-Italic (or Post-Proto-Italic) forms like **amā-fā-s* "you were loving" and **amā-fi-s* "you will love". In other Italic languages, this medial **f* remained: Oscan *fufans* "they were" (= Latin **fubant* = *erant*), Faliscan *carefo* (= Latin *carēbō*). But in Latin, medial **f* [β] hardened into a stop *b*, giving the endings *-bās* and *-bis* and separating them thoroughly from the verb *fīō*.

See [this paper](https://www.dlib.si/stream/URN:NBN:SI:DOC-UL0WUMHF/b5f71191-1211-413f-aec2-7080a96668f4/PDF) for more information. This paper also points out that these tenses are also seen in Celtic, and that their origin is much less cut-and-dry than I make it sound.

Comment: Interesting that the future and imperfect markers have the same origin! That lead to yet another question: [Is the same root twice in *fiebam*?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6487/79)

Comment: Excellent, and easy to follow. And I am glad to know as a bonus that -bo and -bam are also related.

Answer (score 4):

### Side question: *fīō* and *faciō* seem to be unrelated.

*Faciō* "to make" comes from the Proto-Italic root **θaki-*, probably from PIE **dheh₁* "put" (compare Greek *tí-thē-mi*, English "do"). I haven't seen a good explanation of the **k*, but the **θ* seems to be attested in other Italic languages. In Latin, **θ* at the start of words later turned into *f*.

*Fīō* "to become" comes from the Proto-Italic root *fui-*, from PIE **bhuH-* "become". This verb was rather defective even in Proto-Italic, and only had three tenses: the present indicative, present subjunctive, and perfect indicative.

Since *fīō* was so useful, and not a full verb, it was eventually "scrapped for parts" in Latin: its perfect forms (with the stem *fu-*) were stolen by *esse* "to be" to act as its past tense, while its present indicative and subjunctive forms (with the stem *fi-*) were stolen by *faciō* to act as its passive.