# Does 'fiebam' contain the same root twice?

Tags: language-evolution, morphology, conjugation, irregular-words, imperfectum

I learned from [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6484/79) and its answers that the imperfect marker *-ba-* comes from the same PIE root as *fui* and *fio*.
What about the form *fiebam* (and other persons) then?
Does it contain the same root twice (*fi-* and *-ba-*)?

If yes, how is this possible?
It certainly does not look like reduplication.
I imagine that the similarity of the two elements was forgotten and the imperfect form of *fieri* was introduced by analogy to the rest of Latin conjugation.
Or perhaps it arose through periphrasis, with the same verb as the auxiliary and the main verb (cf. Italian *ho avuto*).

I find this a little confusing, so I would appreciate if someone could set me on the right track here.

Comment: The _similarity forgotten_ is attested in a different context: Latin _mecum_ and _tecum_ passed into Spanish as _migo_ and _tigo_ but somewhat lost the _with_ meaning and later "reacquired" a less evolved _cum_ particle to form [_conmigo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ALfVarA) and [_contigo_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AVM506G), so both words have the _cum_ root twice.

Comment: Its almost certain that by the Roman times, the formant *-ba-* was no longer perceived as bearing any root meaning by itself. Also, your terminology is slightly off. Stem is part of a word that fusional ending attaches to, *fi-/fie-* (irregular for this verb). You probably mean *root*. as both components likely come, as you noticed, from the PIE root *bhu-*. But since -ba- became part of the ending, it may no longer be called a root. It may have been in PI, if it was a separate word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It seems so.

According to [Hriberšek](https://www.dlib.si/stream/URN:NBN:SI:DOC-UL0WUMHF/b5f71191-1211-413f-aec2-7080a96668f4/PDF), the imperfect and future were most likely periphrastic constructions, with forms of **fu(i)-* following the main verb. He cites Sihler 1995 comparing this to the future tense in Romance: Late Latin *cantāre habeō* > Romance **cantare-habjo* > French *chanterai*.

It seems like this periphrasis is very old (probably dating from Proto-Italic), because Oscan also preserves *fufans*, an imperfect formed on the stem *fu-*. Just like *fiēbās*, this has two forms of the same morpheme in it. But whether the Oscans or Romans saw it as such is unclear.

After the imperfect marker shifted from **-fā-* to *-bā-* in Latin, that disguised the similarity significantly. And even so, *esse* is the one and only Latin root that didn't take this imperfect marker. On the other hand, Oscan clearly had no trouble with *fu-fa-ns* < **bhu-bhu-ā-*, just like English doesn't mind "had had" and similar forms.

However, whether or not the Romans considered the two morphemes similar, they definitely did come from the same PIE root **bhuH-*.